# Adding fields to Pivot Table from another datasource using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've created Pivot Tables before using VBA but my professor recently gave us a bonus that although is not necessary, is driving me nuts.

### Use a VBA Macro to write Region, District, and Store Name to your first report to create a new report

1) My first report looks like this:

```
  Location | Sum of ActNetSales | Sum of PlanNetSales 
 ----------|--------------------|--------------------- 
         1 | $76,170            | $65,172             
       100 | $163,691           | $140,057            
       101 | $34,724            | $29,710             
       104 | $70,501            | $60,322             
       106 | $113,826           | $97,391
```

2) Below is the data source for the above report.

```
Division | Year | Week | Location | SchedDept | PlanNetSales | ActNetSales | AreaCategory 
 ----------|------|------|----------|-----------|--------------|-------------|-------------- 
         5 | 2018 |   10 |      520 |       541 |       1943.2 |    2271.115 | Non-Comm     
         5 | 2018 |   10 |      520 |       608 |       4378.4 |    5117.255 | Non-Comm     
         5 | 2018 |   10 |      520 |      1059 |       1044.8 |     1221.11 | Comm         
         5 | 2018 |   10 |      520 |      1126 |         6308 |    7372.475 | Non-Comm
```

3) My professor wants me to add the following information to the above table: *Region*, *District* and *Store Name*. However, these 3 fields are from a different data source then the above report. Below is the data source for the 3 fields I've listed.

```
  Division | Location | LocationName | Region | RegionName | District | DistrictName 
 ----------|----------|--------------|--------|------------|----------|-------------- 
         5 |        1 | Location 1   |      3 | Region 3   |       18 | District 18  
         5 |        4 | Location 4   |      5 | Region 5   |       32 | District 32  
         5 |        5 | Location 5   |      3 | Region 3   |       19 | District 19  
         5 |        6 | Location 6   |      5 | Region 5   |       28 | District 28
```

I've created what he's asking above by joining the 2 tables (created a key by concatenating the foreign keys - *location* and *division*: to make a unique key and using a basic index/match ) and just creating a Pivot Table from that but I want to try my best to solve the bonus! Unfortunately, I don't have Power Query so I had to do it this way. I've tried searching up the above and I can't find any good resources. Is there anything you can suggest or just point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Comment: macros to do powerquery - http://excelunplugged.com/2018/01/23/modifying-power-query-m-code-with-vba/

Comment: well-written question. welcome to [so]!

Comment: @Ctznkane525 unfortunately I don't think macbook supports power query but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is it cheating to modify your table under (2) to add the columns region, district, and storename using VLOOKUP on the third table?   The second table would then have raw data, and extra columns of constructed data, effectively joining it to the third table using the Excel VLOOKUP trick rather than an actual SQL table join.

Then you can just use the expanded, joined table as your one Pivot Table source.

Cheating is legal in love, war, and IT solutions.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately, I have already done that but I want to try to emulate his method! Thank you for your suggestion however

Comment: Normally, one clicks on the arrows to indicate the answer was acknowledged as an answer.